# Entity Framework Clob Performance Issue

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ado.net, clob

I have a table contains a column as CLOB type. It takes a lot of time while fetching from that table by using entity framework.
I found a solution for ADO.net oracle command like this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = -1;
```

How can I set InitialLOBFetchSize property for entity framework ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861994/setting-fetch-size-in-entity-framework does this help you?

Comment: I tried but didn't worked for me. I think that fetchsize and initiallobfetchsize are different.

Comment: well this is going to be a nasty solution but what you can do is 
create a new class lets' say PERSON, add all the columns of the query to the class as properties then
make an extension method that takes the sql query as a parameter 
then use OracleCommand to execute the query and finally convert the result into 
List<PERSON>